# Winform Application C# Printing Whole array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am new to c# and trying to insert a number from a textbox and I have adding a button to submit the number. I then want it to be added to the array and outputted onto the listbox. However, I am having the whole array outputted onto 
Thanksthe listbox instead. How do I only show the number being entered?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_ITEMS; i++)
{
    if (i < index)
lstHoldValue.Items.Add(numArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  You're contradicting yourself.  Do you want the numbers in your array to be listed in the list box or not?

Comment: Yeah but only the number entered by the user. otherwise the program will display the whole array for example, user enters 1, then enters 2, but :

1,
1 
2 , would be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clearing your listbox first. The code below should do the job:

```
lstHoldValue.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_ITEMS; i++)
{
    if (i < index)
        lstHoldValue.Items.Add(numArray[i]);//show array in a listbox
}
```

Comment: OMG you're a star. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only want the new item added to the listbox.
If so, changes this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_ITEMS; i++)
{
    if (i < index)
        lstHoldValue.Items.Add(numArray[i]);//show array in a listbox
}
```

to:

```
lstHoldValue.Items.Add(numArray[this.index-1]);//add last inserted item to listbox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
lstHoldValue.Items.clear();
```

before the loop to remove the elements of the List
or juste replace the loop by :

```
listBox1.Items.Add(txtInitialise.Text);
txtInitialise.Text = "";
```

to add the elements one by one